# Execute command in directories that DON'T contain a certain file extension

Tags: command-line, directory, find, execute-command

I'm looking for a way, to find all (sub-)folders that DO NOT contain a certain file type (*.log) and then execute a command within that folder. All my simulation folders contain three different files: *.bat, *.par and *pm. To start the simulation I use the command

`find . -name "*.bat" -exec bash -c ' dir=$(dirname "$1"); cd "$dir"; startcommand start.bat ' sh {} \;`

So it's looking for all folders that DO contain ***.bat** and then executes the starting command. As soon as the simulation starts a new file type is created: ***.log**. Now I need a command that will check all folders that DO NOT contain a ***.log** file and execute the starting command inside of these directories.

I already have found a way to list all folders that do not contain *.log.

```
find ./* -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -i -q "\.log$"' ';' -print
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to realize the last step of getting into that directory and executing the startcommand. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is where the GNU `find` command's `-execdir` may be useful:

> ```
>    -execdir command ;
>
>    -execdir command {} +
>           Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the  subdirec‐
>           tory  containing  the  matched  file,  which is not normally the
>           directory in which you started find.
> ```

Ex. given

```
$ tree subdir?
subdir1
├── bar.log
└── foo.bat
subdir2
└── foo.bat
subdir3
├── bar.log
└── foo.bat

0 directories, 5 files
```

then

```
$ find . -name '*.bat' -execdir sh -c 'set -- *.log; [ -e "$1" ] || echo "${PWD##*/} has no log file"' {} \;
subdir2 has no log file
```

Replace the thing on the RHS of `||` with the command that you wish to run.